# Error in R with Inner join. I am trying to inner join to excel sheets and create a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, inner-join

This is my code. I am having errors with inner_join

```
transactions %>%
  inner_join(donanations, by = "Date") %>%
  group_by(quantity) +
  ggplot()
```

I was expecting to join and create a plot

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Did you misspell `donations`? (If, however, those were not R dataframes, but rather Excel sheet names there might be a catastrophic lack of data input. Need clarification. Need at minimum `str(transactions);str(donanations)` and all complete error messages. Voting to close for lack of details.